# Defining custom events in app framework YUI

Tags: events, yui

I have problem with defining custom event in my app framework. Definition is correct, it works with calling it by this:

```
Y.one('#foo').on('event', fn)
```

but when I want to use it in app framework, in events section, it doesn't work. I tried with this code:

```
events: {
    '.button': {
        'event': 'functionName'
    },
    '.button': {
         click: 'otherFn'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The App framework uses event delegation. You need to support delegation in your synthetic event. Check out [Creating an Arrow Event for DOM Subscription](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/synth-example.html) for an example.